# Алгоритм суммирования числа при определных данных из базы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица table1 в ней поля userneme(text), segodchislo(date), zaxodchislo(date).

Как сделать так чтобы скрипт считал сумму. Например
есть базовая переменная $obshsumma равная 1 и если при добавлении в таблицу новой записи по segodchislo(date) смотрел на поле zaxodchislo и если там стоит значение 0000-00-00 то добавлял в переменную еще значение 1. 
Как только появляется новая запись по segodchislo(date) и у предыдущей записи поле zaxodchislo содержит дату, т.е. не 0000-00-00 то возвращал $obshsumma в значение 1.

Comment: А что такое 'предыдущая запись' ? в sql нет такого понятия. все определяет сортировка. И вы определитесь для чего это надо. Если посчитать количество подходящих по условию записей с учетом существующих в базе до начала работы php скрипта, то надо просто давать запрос вида `select count(1) from tab where ...` а если все данные проходят через постоянно запущенный php скрипт - то на стороне php ...

Comment: Приведите пример таблицы из нескольких записей и результат расчета, каким вы его хотите увидеть. Очень желательно продублировать данные на sqlfiddle.com чтобы можно было попробовать вживую.